# How to write the hypograph formulation of maximization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Given the minimization problem

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {x} {\text{minimize}} & f_0 (x) \\ \text{subject to} & f_i (x) \le 0 \end{array} $$

its [epigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics)) formulation is

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {x, t} {\text{minimize}} & t\\ \text{subject to} & f_0 (x) \leq t \\ & f_i (x) \le 0 \end{array} $$

However, if the original problem is as follows

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {x} {\text{maximize}} & g (x) \\ \text{subject to} & g_i (x) \le 0 \quad\text{(or maybe } g_i (x) \ge 0)\end{array} $$

what would be the corresponding [hypograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypograph_(mathematics)) formulation?

---

My first try is this formulation but I am not entirely sure if my intuition is correct

\begin{aligned}
\underset {x, t} {\text{maximize}} \quad &t \\
\text{subject to} \quad &g_i(x) \le 0 \quad \text{(or maybe } g_i(x) \ge 0)\\
&g(x) \ge t
\end{aligned}

Or should it be

\begin{aligned}
\underset {x, t} {\text{minimize}} \quad &-t \\
\text{subject to} \quad &g_i(x) \le 0 \quad \text{(or maybe } g_i(x) \ge 0)\\
&g(x) \ge t
\end{aligned}

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: Is the objective to be maximised even concave?

Comment: Under the context of my engineering problem, I am not sure that every realization is concave but at this moment please considered it as concave to make thing simple.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thank you for your tutorial, now I know that double dollar sign actually center align the equation !

Comment: It seems correct to me.  However, I don't see what this has to do with convex optimization, for you mentioned nothing about the convexity or concavity of the objective functions